# How to vertically align font awesome icon to the left with br texts

Tags: css

I have icon with list of numbers to the left of icon

```
<div>
    <i id=ico class='icon icon-2x icon-phone'></i>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.text {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#ico {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But, I have this result,

[image]

And, I want to achieve this result using css. To center the icon beside the numbers.

[image]

Here is my jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/1224/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display: flex` property works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/F3KyK/1264/

```css
div.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px;
}
.text {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

/* #ico {
    vertical-align: middle;
} */

.icon-box {
  
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
    <i id=ico class='icon icon-2x icon-phone'></i>
    <div class="icon-box">
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>         <br>
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>         <br>
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JSmith, it's my pleasure :)

Comment: But, I have a problem, Texts are not aligned right here -> http://prntscr.com/klps9b
here's the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/1284/

Comment: @JSmith, You should add min-width property to your icon element. For further explanation see jsfiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/F3KyK/1298/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178556/discussion-between-vsm-and-jsmith).

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.text {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
    <i id=ico class='icon icon-2x icon-phone'></i>
    <div class="list">
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
      <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the phone number spans in a div, then give that div and the icon `display: table-cell`:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#ico {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

div>div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i id=ico class='icon icon-2x icon-phone'></i>
  <div>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span> <br>
    <span class="text">123-4567-890</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you liked my answer you can upvote it and/or accept it.